# ionic 4 create dynamic Multi step Form from Json

Tags: ionic4

have to create multi step signup form from api response( JSON )
form can contain upto 3 pages and should support text field, select box and checkbox group.
The form should support the following validations.
a.  Required
b.  Regex(Input should match the regex configured in json.)
c.  min and max value(text field only)

Each page should have a front and back button at the bottom and final page should contain submit page.
When the next button is clicked, all the fields in the page should be validated. If there are any errors, they should be highlighted.
If not, user should be taken to the next page. When submit is clicked, the value of all the form fields should be collected as a key value pair and sent to the service for processing.

Comment: Please show your attempt with a code example

Comment: Thanks @Philip .. I'm new to ionic, So i tried with static  form. can you please send samples for Multi step form creation in Ionic 4.